# Floor lamp - what is this part?

Tags: floor, lamp

[image]

I would like to repair this floor lamp. The piece in the picture has snapped but I’ve no idea what it’s called to get a new part. Can anyone help?

Comment: Replace the entire socket with a new one the threads are usually 1/4" pipe but those look larger to me , I haven't purchased a lamp socket in a while but they are usually less than 10$ for a switched version.

Answer (score 5):

**Pendant lamp holder** or Pendant socket (or perhaps Pendant lamp socket, you never can tell what mixture of words will work best when there's a choice.) That's a very typical stock design with the large threads to hold the shade. As Ed says, you replace the whole thing.

If you can't find one with threads on the back end (since pendant can mean "hanging by a cord" as well as just "designed to hang down", drop the "pendant" but then you have to sort out the ones with the large threads to hold the shade.

Here's an example in black:
[image]

And one in white that looks similar to yours: [image]